# Program terminates instead of continuing

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I need to program a latin square for my class project. Here is the WIP code:

```
order_str = input ("Input the order of the latin square: ")
order_int = int(order_str)
if order_int > 9:
    print("*** Invalid order of square ***")
    print("*** (must be between 1 and 9) ***")
    print(" ")
    print("Program halted")
else:
    top_left_str = input ("Input the top-left number: ")
    top_left_int = int(top_left_str)

if 1 <= top_left_int <= 6:
    A = 0
else:
    print("*** Invalid order of top-left number ***")
    print("*** (must be between 1 and 6) ***")
    print(" ")
    print("Program halted")

for A in range(order_int):
        for B in range((A+order_int+1), (A+top_left_int)):
            print(B, end = ' ')
```

Instead of continuing into the for loop, the program terminates after I enter a valid input for top_left_str. If I enter an invalid one, it prints out the second else. What am I not understanding about if/else and for? I've tried putting the for loop into the second if-statment, but only gets the same results.

Comment: What values of `order_int` and `top_left_int` are you entering?

Comment: 8 and 1, respectively

Comment: Then the inner loop becomes `for B in range(9, 1)`, and it's empty. Unless you specify a negative step, the range will be empty if its `end` is less than `start`.

Comment: Of course it's the simplest solution. Thank you.